# Is the DefaultHttpAsyncClient thread safe? And why the start() method is mandatory?

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, client

I'm using the [HttpAsyncClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/) library by Apache. I don't understand a couple of things:

1) Is the `DefaultHttpAsyncClient` thread safe? Can I reuse the same instance of the client to make multiple, concurrent, requests?

2) Why do I need to `start()` the client before being able to make a request?

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
DefaultHttpAsyncClient client = new DefaultHttpAsyncClient();
client.start(); // If the client is not started, the request will never be made
Future<HttpResponse> future = client.execute(httpGet, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

    public void failed(Exception arg0) {
    }

    public void completed(org.apache.http.HttpResponse arg0) {
    }

    public void cancelled() {
    }

});

HttpResponse httpResponse = future.get();
```

Comment: As for 2, thanks, been stumped why nothing happened :)